# What is an efficient way to do a video crossfade with FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

Doing a crossfade between two pieces of video content is actually quite complicated in FFmpeg. There is no “crossfade” filter like there is for audio.

What’s an efficient way to do it?

Comment: This answer needs to get a LOT more upvotes... Mark, I would so love you forever if you added cross-fading for the audio too...

Comment: As soon as I figure out how, I'll add it. I think audio crossfade is snap, tho', do believe that there's a simple filter for it.

Comment: I simply added `[0:a][1:a] acrossfade=d=1 [audio]` to the filter and then `-map "[audio]" ` to the command and it worked. If you like, give it a test and update the answer!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [crossfade between 2 videos using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg)

Comment: I like the answer given here far more than the answers at the question for which I marked this a duplicate.

Answer (score 24):

### **TL;DR version:**

This example performs video only, assuming both video clips are the same resolution, frame rate, etc. This will create a 1-second fade in between fadeoutclip and fadeinclip. Assume that fadeoutclip is 10 seconds long. Note that this is formatted for clarity: it's really one line of code.

```
ffmpeg -i fadeoutclip.mp4 -i fadeinclip.mp4 -an \
-filter_complex "\
    [0:v]trim=start=0:end=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[firstclip]; \
    [1:v]trim=start=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[secondclip]; \
    [0:v]trim=start=9:end=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc]; \
    [1:v]trim=start=0:end=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc]; \
    [fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, \
                fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein]; \
    [fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p, \
                fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout]; \
    [fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo]; \
    [fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo]; \
    [fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade]; \
    [firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3[output] \
    " \
-map "[output]" <add in encoding part here>
```

### **Full Version:**

Here is an explanation of what this was all about:

**Input Specification...obvious**

```
ffmpeg -i fadeoutclip.mp4 -i fadeinclip.mp4 -an
```

**Creating a `filter_complex`:** [assuming you already understand filter complexes:](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Filtering)

```
-filter_complex
```

*First we break the two streams into two pieces each using the [trim filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim):* the content and the cross fade section. The fade out is broken into content and fade section, while the fade in is cut into the fade section and content. Total of four sections.

Note that strictly speaking, we don't *have* to break the cross fade sections out: we COULD just specify the fade out and fade in times for the two video clips. However, by doing this, we:

- Follow the methodology typically used by GUI video editors
- [Avoid the frustrating complexity of the `overlay` filter's usage](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)
- Ensure that the solution is as general as possible (i.e. reusable code)
- Allow us to pre-process and post-process the crossfade section as necessary (not done here)

*Each of these four sections specifies:* start time (seconds), end time (seconds), and the mysterious [`setpts=PTS-STARTPTS` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts), which essentially makes each video subclip start at 0 seconds. This will be vital when re-compositing them.

Note that the `s=0` specifiers are redundant, and the `setpts` filter for the `s=0` ones is ALSO redundant. However, both are specified redundantly to allow the start time change from 0, without breaking the filter complex. Also, the second content clip runs to the end, so the `e=` part (end=) is not specified.

```
    [0:v]trim=s=0:e=9,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[firstclip];
    [1:v]trim=s=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[secondclip];
    [0:v]trim=s=9:e=10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeoutsrc];
    [1:v]trim=s=0:e=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fadeinsrc];
```

*Next, we specify the fade in and fade out:* We first add an alpha (transparency) channel to both fade sections by [specifying a pixel format of `yuva420p`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format). You can actually use any format that provides an alpha channel.

[Next in this filter subcomplex we specify one to fade out, and one to fade in.](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fade) The `alpha=1` means that the video itself will not darken, only the transparency amount will "fade". `st` means start, `d` means duration.

```
    [fadeinsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,      
                fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadein];
    [fadeoutsrc]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,
                fade=t=out:st=0:d=1:alpha=1[fadeout];
```

*What is this?:* [The `fifo` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fifo) ensures that there is buffer space available in the filter complex. *Amazingly, this is NOT the default.* If you don't do this, the crossfade could fail if the output of the stage above overruns the overlay filter below. *Yeah, I know what you're thinking right now. [It is indeed an FFMPEG bug](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4804)*.

```
    [fadein]fifo[fadeinfifo];
    [fadeout]fifo[fadeoutfifo];
```

*[Now, overlay the two fade sections:](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1)* By making sure the two crossfade sections are the same size, we don't have to worry about [the rather nasty options the overlay filter takes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) (and so we ignore them here):

```
    [fadeoutfifo][fadeinfifo]overlay[crossfade];
```

*Finally, we line up our three segments [using the concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat).*

```
    [firstclip][crossfade][secondclip]concat=n=3[output]
```

### **And now, map the output pad as your video source.**

**DO NOT FORGET** to set the pixel format TO WHAT YOU NORMALLY USE (typically `yuv420p`), as the crossfade section will have set it to `yuv420` on the output channel! [(as we didn't specify it, you can using the overlay arguments)](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) Of course, if you WANT `yuv420`, then you're fine :-)

```
-map "[output]" <add your normal encoding part here>
```

You can then recombine audio in later (outside of the scope of this Q&A)

Comment: In the latest ffmpeg, it needs to be `trim=start=0:end=9`, (rather than `trim=st=0:e=9,`..

Comment: But seriously, this is gonna have to be the best answer on FFMPEG I have ever seen, and the clearest ffmpeg explanation ever.

Comment: Man, that's going to go to my head :-) Thanks for the props!!!!

Comment: No worries. Please update the answer especially with =trim=start=0 as right now it doesn't work with the latest ffmpeg

Comment: Latest ffmpeg version gives me this error: `Filter setpts has an unconnected output` for the script. I already changed the trim parameters to start and end.

Comment: @JoostMeijer Then you might have adapted the example wrongly. Works for me as posted.

Comment: You are right @slhck, my output syntax was invalid. It works now, with the updated trim=start=0:end=10 parameters.

Comment: FFmpeg has an xfade filter now, see my answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1628904/48078

Answer (score 5):

FFmpeg now has an [`xfade` (crossfade) filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade).

[image]

You can use this on two inputs via a complex filterchain:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 \
  -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=2.5" \
  output.mp4
```

Here, the videos will be concatenated, and after 2.5 seconds (`offset=2.5`) the first one will fade over to the second one, with a fade duration of one second (`duration=1`).

You can see examples of what crossfades are available on the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Xfade).

Comment: When trying a command identical to this I get the following error: `Error while filtering: Cannot allocate memory... Failed to inject frame into filter network: Cannot allocate memory`. I'm using a build compiled from the latest version of FFmpeg. Any idea what could be wrong here?

Comment: @HashimAziz No idea, I would try with a recent stable build (v4.3.2 at the time of writing) and if it works there, you could file a bug report (https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html).

Comment: YAY! Wonderful that they have it! That's so much better that the pipe-o-rama I had to put together!

Comment: How to do this when the input is a list of images of arbitrary count?

Comment: @jjxtra In that case you'd normally write a script to assemble the ffmpeg input dynamically. There are a few slideshow generator scripts out there that basically do this, e.g. https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-video-slideshow-scripts