# ffmpeg crossfading multiple images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I am trying to cross-fade multiple images. I found some helpful piece of code in [**this superuser thread**](https://superuser.com/a/778967/466239). So far I am stuck at this point:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img0.jpg -loop 1 -i img1.jpg -i img2.jpg -f lavfi -i color=black \
-filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=480x320,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=3:d=0.25:alpha=1[va0]; \
[1:v]scale=480x320,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=3:d=0.25:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=6:d=0.25:alpha=1[va1]; \
[2:v]scale=480x320,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=6:d=0.25:alpha=1[va2]; \
[3:v]scale=480x320,trim=duration=9[over0];\
[over0][va0]overlay[over1]; \
[over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[over2]; \
[over2][va2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
-c:v libx264 -map [outv] -y -t 9 outcross.mp4
```

After the 2nd clip it fades to black. It seem to have missed something.

I am still a newbie to FFmpeg so I am not too familiar on doing multiple operations.

Comment: actually charmath your edit is probably fine I just couldn't see that you had preserved the link http://i.imgur.com/efGcfSk.png  'cos it was just showing in green rather than blue in this screen

Comment: @barlop I'm sorry... this appears to be fine here... blue link.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, I wasn't aware! And thanks for the hint!

Comment: @Chamath just made it bold and blue, that's clearer

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a `-loop 1` for the third image.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img0.jpg -loop 1 -i img1.jpg -loop 1 -i img2.jpg -f lavfi -i color=black -filter_complex "\
[0:v]scale=480x320,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=3:d=0.25:alpha=1[va0]; \
[1:v]scale=480x320,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=3:d=0.25:alpha=1,fade=t=out:st=6:d=0.25:alpha=1[va1]; \
[2:v]scale=480x320,format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=6:d=0.25:alpha=1[va2]; \
[3:v]scale=480x320,trim=duration=9[over0];\
[over0][va0]overlay[over1]; \
[over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[over2]; \
[over2][va2]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" -c:v libx264 -map [outv] -y -t 9 outcross.mp4
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493797/how-to-fade-two-images-with-ffmpeg) for a different approach.

Answer (score -1):

It can be done with the framerate filter:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence#Slideshow_with_crossfading_between_the_pictures

Comment: Welcome to Super User! On this Q&A site we try to provide [good answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) to questions people post. A part of this is including the answer in your post, [instead of simply providing a link to another page that might answer the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259). Please edit your answer to include the actual solution to the posted question. Refer to [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing) for help.