# FFMPEG Crossfade videos changes video resolution

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing

I am currently using the command from this question to crossfade two videos:

[crossfade between 2 videos using ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/778762/crossfade-between-2-videos-using-ffmpeg)

My command:

```
ffmpeg -i firstVideo.mp4 -i secondVideo.mp4 -f lavfi -i color=black -    filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0];\
[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[va1];\
[2:v]scale=640x360,trim=duration=9[over];\
[over][va0]overlay[over1];\
[over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
 -vcodec libx264 -map [outv] output.mp4
```

This crossfade animation works fine, except for it shrinks the video to 480x360 instead of the desired 640x360. The meta information will falsely show that the dimensions are 640x360, but I am certain they are not.

I am also certain that both input videos are exactly 640x360.

I am guessing that the shrinking is due to the pixel format `yuva420p`, but I'm not sure what other options I have. I have tried changing the pixel format but nothing has worked so far.

The command given above runs without any errors.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i firstVideo.mp4 -i secondVideo.mp4 -f lavfi -i "color=black:s=640x360:d=9" 
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=out:st=4:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[va0];\
[1:v]format=pix_fmts=yuva420p,fade=t=in:st=0:d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+4/TB[va1];\
[2:v][va0]overlay[over1];\
[over1][va1]overlay=format=yuv420[outv]" \
 -vcodec libx264 -map [outv] output.mp4
```

The color filter outputs a 320x240 video unless specified otherwise. The scale filter seeks to preserve the source aspect ratio - 4:3 in this case, so the video is encoded as 640x360 but with a display aspect ratio of 4:3 so shows as 480x360.